# Problem with Showing the website (hostet on IIS) when connection with Public IP

Tags: .net, azure, iis, azure-sql-database

the deployed an API (.Net Core) and a Frontend on 2 different VM.
For the Database i run Azure SQL Database.
When trying to access the frontend through private IP (Local Network) everything is working, i can call and add data in the database.
But when using a Public IP, i can only see the UI but it can't communicate with the Database(API)
I was confused because everything works perfect in the private Network.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated the problem with Showing the website (hosted on IIS) when connection with Public IP. I'm assuming you're using IIS-Express.

> IIS-Express only connects to localhost by default.

1. Run Visual Studios as administrator.
2. Change the Binding Protocols and allow the incoming from Public IP
   addresses as mentioned in the document: Johan Driessen’s Post on
   Accessing an IIS Express site from a remote computer | [Here](https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer/).
3. That you must restart IIS Express for the modifications to take
   effect.

To go around this, edit the IIS-Express application config file at: C:\Users<username>\My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config  and change the site's binding information.

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":xxxx:" /> 

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":xxxx:machineName" /> 

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":xxxx:10.1.10.123" />
```

OR

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:xxxxxx:*" />
```

> The simplest method to accomplish this was to right-click on the IIS
> Express icon and select quit. The icon will vanish, so you won't be
> able to restart it that way. Instead, launch a debug session for your
> web project using Visual Studio. It will restart IIS. As an added
> benefit, you can validate the changes by right-clicking on the IIS
> icon, locating your web app under "View Sites," and then the IP
> addresses from which your app may now be accessible. It should display
> your binding modifications right there.

Comment: i can access each VM speratly with Public Adress. 
the Api is reachblae with Public Adress 
a i used this public adress to connect with the Frontend. 

But when connecting to frontend with public ip it's not connecting to API. 
when connecting on the Frontend VM (Localhost) it working normally.